# Mac OS Sierra "ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!"

Tags: mysql, macos

While I am trying to login to the MySQL server after a fresh install I am getting following error

```
ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!
```

After a long research, I  got the following answer which I am going to post

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the existing errors from the **data** folder

```
rm *.err /usr/local/mysql/data/
```

For more information, [enter link description here](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/mysql-error-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file/)you can find it following link

[[Solved] ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/mysql-error-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file/)